# How can i type a certain character in Java?

Tags: java, unicode

I tried many things to type a certain Unicode character at current cursor like Chinese character etc.

The way what i used is using a Clipboard and Robot.

First, save contents already in clipboard to restore contents to the original.
Second, set contents of clipboard with what i want to type.
Third, invoke Ctrl + V key using Robot.
Fourth, restore contents of clipboard to the original we saved in first step.

```
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();

Transferable originalContent = clipboard.getContents(null);
StringSelection newContents = new StringSelection(str);

clipboard.setContents(newContents, newContents);

keyboardRobot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
keyboardRobot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
keyboardRobot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
keyboardRobot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

clipboard.setContents(originalContent, null);
```

Well, it works roughly. But usually pasting text happens earlier than setting contents that original contents are pasted. And even, clipboard are not available sometimes so i think that this method is not really very good method to type Unicode.

Would you help me? :( Please help me...

Comment: Seems like it would be easier to type &nnnn and have your program convert the ampersand string to a Unicode character.

Comment: Java should support Unicode by default, what are you trying to make?
Are you typing Unicode in your Java code, or in a GUI?

Comment: @Robotia Anywhere. While program is running.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc that can be proceed with only keyboard stroke?

Comment: No.  Your keyboard input would have to be interpreted by Java code in a Java application.